# Parsing A UPnP Response In Swift?

Tags: swift, parsing, cocoaasyncsocket

This question may not need to be so specific, but I am working on a project that is searching for UPnP devices (working great).

I get the data like so;

```
func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromAddress address: NSData!, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject!) {

        var host: NSString?
        var port1: UInt16 = 0
        GCDAsyncUdpSocket.getHost(&host, port: &port1, fromAddress: address)
        //print(host)

        let response: NSString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        print(response)

    }
```

The data response is returned as a NSString, and looks like so;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=120
DATE: Sun, 31 Jan 2016 22:47:45 GMT
ST: upnp:rootdevice
USN: uuid:f7a65ab0-f527-4b85-a8ad-68104aa2b322::upnp:rootdevice
EXT:
SERVER: Linux/BHR4 UPnP/1.1 MiniUPnPd/1.8
LOCATION: http://192.168.1.1:49420/rootDesc.xml
OPT: "http://schemas.upnp.org/upnp/1/0/"; ns=01
01-NLS: 1
BOOTID.UPNP.ORG: 1
CONFIGID.UPNP.ORG: 1337


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=600
EXT: 
Location: http://192.168.1.1:1901/root.xml
SECURELOCATION.UPNP.ORG: https://192.168.1.1:1902/root.xml
Server: Linux/3.4 UPnP/2.0 bhr4/1.2
ST: upnp:rootdevice
USN: uuid:9518ecfc-cf2f-57e4-bb23-5182aa6a23cd::upnp:rootdevice
DATE: Wed, 19 Jan 2000 02:39:56 GMT
BOOTID.UPNP.ORG: 1


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=600
EXT: 
Location: http://192.168.1.1:1901/root.xml
SECURELOCATION.UPNP.ORG: https://192.168.1.1:1902/root.xml
ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:ManageableDevice:2
USN: uuid:9518acfc-cf2f-57e4-cc23-5a12aa6a23cd::urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:ManageableDevice:2
Server: Linux/3.4 UPnP/2.0 bhr4/1.2
DATE: Wed, 19 Jan 2000 02:39:56 GMT
BOOTID.UPNP.ORG: 1
```

I have some understanding of how to parse XML or JSON responses, but being that this response seems to just be a lengthy string, I am trying to figure out how I could parse the data into a dictionary so I could do a;

`for item in response {
print(item.location)
}`

This is not necessarily specific to UPnP, but an overall premise to grasp.

Comment: Where are you getting `data` from? Somewhere further back in the chain you should be able to work with the HTTP headers in the response, rather than just a string. Then you would have no parsing to do.

Comment: Hi Michael - Most of this is handled via the CocoaASyncSocket request that's awaiting the UPnP responses.  Not sure if that answers your question, but I updated my question with the full function.

Comment: Their documentation doesn't tell you much about that NSData. You might want to add `cocoaasyncsocket` as a tag to the question to get more targeted responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a swift UPNP library not so long ago.
Here is one way how I did it with regular expressions:
https://github.com/ambientlight/ambientUPNP/blob/master/ambientUPNP/SSDPMessage.swift

You can use for parsing SSDP messages, however for UPNP GENA events you should not use this approach since they are over TCP, and therefore you have a stream-socket which you should read as a stream accordingly. Take a look here:
https://github.com/ambientlight/ambientUPNP/blob/master/ambientUPNP/components/HTTPInternals.swift

**Reference (reading from UDP socket - fixed length)**:
https://github.com/ambientlight/ambientUPNP/blob/master/ambientUPNP/SSDPServer.swift

```
self.readMulticastSocket = try PosixInternals.initMulticastUDPSocket(SSDPDefaultPort, multicastAddress: SSDPMulticastAddress)
let readMulticastSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ, UInt(readMulticastSocket), 0, _readMulticastQueue)

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(readMulticastSource) {

     do {

          let (data, senderAddress) = try PosixInternals.recvData(self.readMulticastSocket, readSize: SSDPDefaultReadSize)
          let message = try SSDPMessage.messageWithDataAndAddress(data, senderAddress: senderAddress)
          //print("\(message)\n")
          self._processMessage(message)

    } catch {
          print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ambientlight!  I skimmed through your project, but without any documentation, I'm really having a hard time understanding how to import it/incorporate it into my project.  If there are any example projects, or reading, I'd love to try to figure it out.  I'm really struggling with this one.

Comment: I am sorry for that, haven't finished yet. I can give you a suggestion of traversing from SSDPServer init(). It has two dispatch_source event handlers, where whenever the data will be available to read on the socket, I will parse it as SSDPMessage and then pass it to the UPNPControlPoint instance, which will extract the descriptionURL and fetch the device description. It will init the device with it, and then do the same for embedded services. If you need more guidance, we might create a chat here and I can explain in greater details.

Comment: Hi @ambientlight - I'd love to, though I'm not even sure how to create a direct chat with you here on SO.  My apologies for that.  If you see this and can include me, I'd love to learn how to incorporate this.  Thanks!

Comment: @ZbadhabitZ - I have created chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102616/ios-upnp

Comment: I was successfully able to implement this and get it to work!  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @ambientlight if you upgrade your source code it's very helpful and adds sample code and document as well