# Swift discover UPnP devices?

Tags: ios, swift, sonos

I have been searching the web and discoverd that the sonos system can be controlled with POST request with a SOAP body.
My question is ..
How can I discover UPnP devices with swift code? And figure out which device it is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120659/parsing-a-upnp-response-in-swift

Answer (score 3):

check this [UPNP Link](https://github.com/ambientlight/ambientUPNP). In this link  UPNP ControlPoint-oriented stack implementation avaialable. it's useful for you need.

there is another [link](https://github.com/fkuehne/upnpx) it will give you full details of the upnp device type. go through the document once.

Comment: I have look at  it this link. But I have problems to undarstand how to use it. Can you give me a start maybe?

Comment: Yes. So I can get the IP adress for the Sonos speakers.

Comment: Thank you! Can't wait to get home and try it!